# Multiple cursor in form's TextFormField flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, text-cursor

I'm new to flutter & I try to achieve this screen with the below code, in this I'm facing a weird Multiple cursor UI.

**Steps to reproduce this issue:**

- Click randomly any `TextFormField`, the soft keyboard pops up & by pressing the back navigation button at bottom the keyboard hides..
- When i do this process several times the cursor marks are blinking in each of the `TextFormField`.

What was the mistake?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:thought_factory/utils/colors.dart';

class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
static var _keyValidationForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();
TextEditingController _textEditConName = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _textEditConEmail = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _textEditConPassword = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _textEditConConfirmPassword = TextEditingController();
bool isPasswordVisible = false;
bool isConfirmPasswordVisible = false;

@override
void initState() {
isPasswordVisible = false;
isConfirmPasswordVisible = false;
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: AppColors.colorGrey,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            getWidgetImageLogo(),
            getWidgetRegistrationCard(),
          ],
        )),
  ),
);
}

Widget getWidgetImageLogo() {
return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32, bottom: 32),
      child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
    ));
 }

Widget getWidgetRegistrationCard() {
final FocusNode _passwordEmail = FocusNode();
final FocusNode _passwordFocus = FocusNode();
final FocusNode _passwordConfirmFocus = FocusNode();

return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
    ),
    elevation: 10.0,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _keyValidationForm,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text(
                'Register',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0, color: AppColors.colorBlack),
              ),
            ), // title: login
            Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _textEditConName,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                validator: _validateUserName,
                onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordEmail);
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Full name',
                    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
              ),
            ), //text field : user name
            Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _textEditConEmail,
                focusNode: _passwordEmail,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                validator: _validateEmail,
                onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocus);
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email',
                    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.email)),
              ),
            ), //text field: email
            Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _textEditConPassword,
                focusNode: _passwordFocus,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                validator: _validatePassword,
                onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                  FocusScope.of(context)
                      .requestFocus(_passwordConfirmFocus);
                },
                obscureText: !isPasswordVisible,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(isPasswordVisible
                          ? Icons.visibility
                          : Icons.visibility_off),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key)),
              ),
            ), //text field: password
            Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _textEditConConfirmPassword,
                  focusNode: _passwordConfirmFocus,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  validator: _validateConfirmPassword,
                  obscureText: !isConfirmPasswordVisible,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(isConfirmPasswordVisible
                            ? Icons.visibility
                            : Icons.visibility_off),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isConfirmPasswordVisible =
                                !isConfirmPasswordVisible;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key))),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.0),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: AppColors.colorAccent,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 5.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_keyValidationForm.currentState.validate()) {
                    _onTappedButtonRegister();
                  }
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
              ),
            ), //button: login
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Already Register? ',
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      splashColor: AppColors.colorAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
                      onTap: () {
                        _onTappedTextlogin();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        ' Login',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors.colorAccent,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

String _validateUserName(String value) {
return value.trim().isEmpty ? "Name can't be empty" : null;
}

String _validateEmail(String value) {
Pattern pattern =
    r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
  return 'Invalid Email';
} else {
  return null;
}
}

String _validatePassword(String value) {
return value.length < 5 ? 'Min 5 char required' : null;
}

String _validateConfirmPassword(String value) {
return value.length < 5 ? 'Min 5 char required' : null;
}

void _onTappedButtonRegister() {}

void _onTappedTextlogin() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AlexLushiku & @nuts for your time, none worked for me, except this solution.. I just made all the `focusNode` local variables to global scope that solved the problem.

Comment: I have same problem but, I think mine is because of I use StatelessWidget, it causes the problem imo. What should I do? Edit: I converted into StatefulWidget, never use Stateless for TextField even you use BLoC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removed the **local scope focusNode** from this method.

```
Widget getWidgetRegistrationCard() {
final FocusNode _passwordEmail = FocusNode(); //removed 
final FocusNode _passwordFocus = FocusNode(); //removed
final FocusNode _passwordConfirmFocus = FocusNode(); //removed
.
. 
.
}
```

& declare it **globally solved** the problem for me.

```
class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
static var _keyValidationForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();

final FocusNode _passwordEmail = FocusNode();  //added globally
final FocusNode _passwordFocus = FocusNode();  //added globally
final FocusNode _passwordConfirmFocus = FocusNode();  //added globally
.
. 
.
```

Comment: What about if you have 20000 textField?

Answer (score 17):

As the [OP answered in comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038010/multiple-cursor-in-forms-textformfield-flutter/57586327#comment98746459_56038010):

> [Declare] all the `focusNode` from local variables to global scope that solved the problem.

I'm using `focusNode` in `Widget build(BuildContext context)` method. Which is showing multiple cursors.

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final FocusNode _emailFocus = FocusNode();
    final FocusNode _passwordFocus = FocusNode();
```

**SOLUTION** - Declare `focusNode` Globally.

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  final FocusNode _emailFocus = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _passwordFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: What about if you have 20000 textField?

Comment: I made different focus node for each textformfield still  I'm getting the same issue

Comment: @lacas wrap your input with a FocusScope widget. It has onFocusChange where you can put your logic of the old FocusNode listener

Comment: May I know what was the issue , because adding focus nodes is never a solution when you have 10+ form fields . Please let me know what made the issue appear