# Flutter Cursor Appearing in two fields at the same time

Tags: flutter

I have problem with flutter textformfield. Like I said in title my app show cursor in two textformfield. It appear when I tap previous textfield. I'm using real phone for test, not tried in emulator. Thanks for any help.
Here image from my app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9JHG.jpg)

```
Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
     height: 20.0,
    ),
    TextFormField(
     decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
     focusNode: _emailFocus,
     onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
      _passwordFocus.nextFocus();
      _fieldFocusChange(
       context, _emailFocus, _passwordFocus);
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      validator: (value) =>
       value.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
      onChanged: (value) {
       setState(() => email = value);
      },
      ),
      SizedBox(
       height: 20.0,
      ),
      TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
        validator: (value) => value.length < 6
        ? 'Enter an password 6+ chars long'
        : null,
        obscureText: true,
        focusNode: _passwordFocus,
        onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
        _passwordFocus.unfocus();
        _submitForm();
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        onChanged: (value) {
         setState(() => password = value);
        },
        ),
        SizedBox(
         height: 20.0,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
         color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
         child: Text('Sign in'),
         onPressed: () {
          _submitForm();
         },
         ),
         SizedBox(height: 12.0),
         Text(error,
          style:
           TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14.0)),
          ],
)),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution from this question:

[Multiple cursor in form's TextFormField flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038010/multiple-cursor-in-forms-textformfield-flutter)

It is same as mine. We did same mistake. When I declare FocusNode global it solve problem.